# How to stop Youtube Annotations when using JWPlayer to Embed Youtube

Tags: jquery, video, youtube, jwplayer

I currently have a website which I'm creating which uses JWPlayer to embed Youtube videos.  I'm using these instructions...

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406725-youtube-video-embed

The code I am using for the video is as follows:

```
<script src="http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/XeGdlzmk.js"></script>

<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
      playerInstance.setup({
      file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9c00Emu5a84",
      width: "100%",
      aspectratio: "16:9",
      autostart: true
      });
</script>
```

However on my videos you can see annotations.  I know you can load in &iv_load_policy=3 into embededed videos to stop them from appearing, but I cannot seem to get it to work.  Please see this example:

http://www.foodreviewed.co.uk/video/lasagna-recipe-beef-cheese-lasagna-christmas-lasagna-recipe/

Does anyone know how to fix this?  Have tried various jQuery "solutions" without any success.

Comment: YouTube Annotations are through their API, they can't be hidden as far as I know.